# Having trouble applying distress bitmap w/ clipping mask vs. opacity mask

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to figure out how to apply a distressed effect using a clipping mask. I am having difficulty recreating what I have next to me on the left, when I try to apply the clipping mask I'm told I'm unable to. I can get the distressed look using an opacity mask, but I'd like to learn how to use a clipping mask like the original artwork was done. Here's what I'm working with[image]

[image]

Here's my file https://filebin.net/b168rps94rnxv940

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a raster texture file that is the problem. You **cannot** create **clipping masks** using raster images.

Use Live Trace to trace the raster texture, converting it to vector. Then it should work for a clipping mask. Be aware, unlike opacity masks,  *clipping* masks do **not** support subtle transparency.... things *must* be black or white.. no grey.

---- but, there's nothing wrong with Opacity Masks.

---

Note that *in your file* there's **no actual masking** taking place.

The distressed *raster* image is merely the *same color* as the jersey. So when it's placed on top of the jersey, the red of the logo appears to be removed. However, it's merely the grey raster image covering the logo, Nothing is masked.